# Why does my old Pinterest username redirect to my new username?

Tags: username, pinterest

I am pretty new to Pinterest so I have not really an idea where to look for info besides the Pinterest help page it self, which did not help me at all.

I have registered a username on Pinterest, let's say `MyFirstPinterest`. But after a while I want to change it to `MySecondPinterest` and I don't want anything to do with the previous name anymore.

But for some reason when I type in `MyFirstPinteres` I get redirected to `MySecondPinterest`. I don't understand how that is possible because the first username doesn't exist anymore.
How is it possible to end up with the new username? I don't want to be associated with the old username anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can change as many times as you want. Pinterest keeps them all and links to the same profile. I contacted them twice. They don't seem to be interested. This is bad for privacy so exporting and importing your pins to a new account could be a solution.